# Uploadify - Random form data that's returned to upload form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

Basically what I'm trying to do is generate an alphanumeric string, which is passed to the php handler, as well as back to the upload form. When the upload is complete, the form then creates a link using the alphanumeric string.

I've gotten everything to work, except for one issue. There is only one random string that's generated, so if you try to upload multiple files at the same time, every one of them has the same string name. I need them each to have different names, but I can't seem to figure out how, while still being able to pass back to the form and the php.

Here's my script:

```
<script>
    function randomString(length, chars) {
        var result = '';
        for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
        return result;
    }
    var sessid = '';
    var data = document.getElementById('data');
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myModal').modal({
            show: false
        });
        $('#mm').modal({
            show: false
        });

        $(function () {
            $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'fileObjName': 'file',
                'fileSizeLimit': '8MB',
                'buttonText': 'BROWSE FILE(S)...',
                'fileTypeExts': '*.JPEG; *.GIF; *.PNG; *.APNG; *.TIFF; *.BMP; *.PDF; *.XCF',
                'cancelImg': 'uploadify-cancel.png',
                'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': 'uploadify.php',
                'formData': randomString(7, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
                'auto': false
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also made a small modification to `jquery.uploadify-3.1.min.js`, which allowed for the random string to be passed back to the form.

```
if (c.inArray("onUploadSuccess", g.overrideEvents) < 0) {
    c("#" + f.id).find(".data").html(" - " + this.settings.post_params);
}
```

If anyone wants to see it all in action, you can see it here: http://icap.me/test/files.php
Ignore the broken design, for now I'm just trying to get it to work.

Comment: Have you considered having PHP handle generating the numbers from the request, rather than having JS do it? You'll get a lot more flexibility that way.

Comment: @NathanTaylor if I could think of a way to pass the data from the php back to the form, I would. Unfortunately I think the only way I could get it to work correctly is for the strings to be generated by the js.

Comment: You can make use of `onUploadSuccess` http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess to parse out the response your PHP application sends.

Comment: @NathanTaylor Ah, thanks. I didn't realize that listened for the response. Just one issue, I'm still trying to get the form to update, but I'm getting a null error, because the id I'm trying to set doesn't exist until the file is selected. I saw the livequery plugin which might help, but I'm trying not to add anything any more resources. Any ideas? Here's my new code, the error is on the getElementByID line. http://jsfiddle.net/xYrzX/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `onUploadStart` handler to set the random string used for the upload.

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'fileObjName': 'file',
            'fileSizeLimit': '8MB',
            'buttonText': 'BROWSE FILE(S)...',
            'fileTypeExts': '*.JPEG; *.GIF; *.PNG; *.APNG; *.TIFF; *.BMP; *.PDF; *.XCF',
            'cancelImg': 'uploadify-cancel.png',
            'swf': 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': 'uploadify.php',
            'auto': false,
            'onUploadStart': function() {
               $("#file_upload").uploadify('settings', 
                                           'formData',
                                           randomString(7, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')) }
        });
```

Comment: I'm sure that wasn't meant to be copied and pasted, but if it was, it didn't work. I tried the following with no luck

http://jsfiddle.net/xYrzX/

If you could possibly point me in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: It was untested. The important point is that you have to call the `settings` method. Otherwise, every upload uses the settings from the original call to `.uploadify`. BTW, you don't need to wrap your `("#file_upload").uploadify` call inside another level of `$(function()...)` -- `$(function()...)` is the same as `$(document).ready(function ()...)`. But I don't think this is related to the problem.

Comment: Remember, the way jQuery works is that everything in the `.ready()` function only gets done once, when the document is loaded. So it never updates the `formData` parameter unless you do something additional to change it. Changing the `rString` variable in your fiddle doesn't do anything to the uploadify settings.

Comment: I just noticed the following in the uploadify documentation for `formData`: "If you plan on setting these values dynamically, this should be done using the ‘settings’ method in the onUploadStart event." I've updated my answer accordingly. Give it a try.

Comment: I got an error with that code (no debug info, just "error"). I'm going to try to mess around with the PHP, to see if I can have more luck with that. I'm still trying to get a solid grip on jQuery.

Comment: I got it figured out for the most part, just one more issue. I'm using onUploadSuccess to listen to the response from the php, and using the php to generate the random string instead. My new issue is that I can't get the form to update, because the id I'm trying to modify doesn't exist until a file is selected, resulting in a null error on page load. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but like I said earlier, I'm still learning the jQuery ropes. Here's my new code, maybe you can throw me one more bone. The error is on the getElementByID line. http://jsfiddle.net/xYrzX/1/

Comment: There's no HTML in the fiddle.

Comment: sorry for the long reply time, I've been out. The ID I'm trying to modify is "data", hence the `document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=data;`

The issue is that "data" isn't created until a file is selected, so the function returns null when the page is loaded.